# find memory leaks when Valgrind shows nothing

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

I am looking for memory leaks in a C++ program on Linux with a heavy legacy background (multi-threaded, using libstdc++ containers). This program is a proxy server, an intermediary for requests from clients to servers.

Valgrind has detected a few ones that are now fixed, and shows nothing more.

But the RSS of the process (resident memory as shown by /proc//stat) still grows on a given repeated stimulus (around 9 bytes per iteration). This is not linear and grows by big steps, probably because the lib c++ containers does memory optimization and the RSS is measured by pages that have a size of 4096 bytes).

As Valgrind finds nothing, I may suspect some recursive calls that grow the stack or some unused and forgotten tables (eg: std::list, std::map, std::string, etc.) that keep growing.

The only methods I see for my search are:

- Reading the code;
- Reduce the scope by deactivating parts of the code;

But these are laborious and time consuming.

- How could I improve my search? Are there tools for finding growing stacks or tables?
- Any other idea about the cause of the leak (except dangling pointers, uncontrolled recursion, growing tables)?

Comment: It's really hard to comment, without information about what your code does.  What you describe can occur if your code has no memory leak, but there is a significant time interval between allocation and release.    It is also common for the library functions that release dynamically allocated memory (`operator delete()`, `free()`, etc) don't return it immediately to the OS (e.g. because releasing memory to the OS, and then requesting a fresh allocation, is more expensive than keeping track and reusing memory that has been released by the program but not released to the OS).

Comment: you can use a custom allocator with some diagnostics for your stl container

Comment: I added information about what the code does: a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/vmware/chap :

To do this, gather a live core of your process (after running an hour's worth of  iterations) then start chap with the path of that core as the only argument.  From the chap prompt, try the following:

```
count used
count free
count leaked
count writable
```

Assuming reported for **used** is signicantly larger than the number reported for **free**, the next thing you want to check is the number for **leaked**.  If that number is non-zero, you actually have leaks in the sense of memory that is no longer referenced.  Follow USERGUIDE.md for some strategies for analyzing that.

If the number for **leaked** is 0 or not significant, but the number for **used** is you likely have some container growth.  Use **summarize used** as the next step.